# How do I perform a non-user login in Flask?

Tags: python, session, flask

I deployed my Flask application into production and I'm having issues with it functioning. After using the application a few times, I start getting internal 500 errors. Per the traceback, it looks like i'm having issues with the session:

```
[Sun Jul 26 19:20:53.476076 2015] [:error] [pid 11281:tid 140153993467648] ERROR:Routing:Request failed: Session is not logged in.
[Sun Jul 26 19:20:53.476356 2015] [:error] [pid 11281:tid 140153993467648]      ERROR:routes:Exception on /bank [POST]
[Sun Jul 26 19:20:53.476367 2015] [:error] [pid 11281:tid 140153993467648] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Jul 26 19:20:53.476370 2015] [:error] [pid 11281:tid 140153993467648]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
[Sun Jul 26 19:20:53.476373 2015] [:error] [pid 11281:tid 140153993467648]     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
[Sun Jul 26 19:20:53.476376 2015] [:error] [pid 11281:tid 140153993467648]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1478, in full_dispatch_request
[Sun Jul 26 19:20:53.476380 2015] [:error] [pid 11281:tid 140153993467648]     response = self.make_response(rv)
[Sun Jul 26 19:20:53.476382 2015] [:error] [pid 11281:tid 140153993467648]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1566, in make_response
[Sun Jul 26 19:20:53.476385 2015] [:error] [pid 11281:tid 140153993467648]     raise ValueError('View function did not return a response')
[Sun Jul 26 19:20:53.476388 2015] [:error] [pid 11281:tid 140153993467648] ValueError: View function did not return a response
```

For this application, I'm using sessions to capture data from a user's input. The user isn't actually logging in to the app. So when a user first, hits my app homepage(/), the function "store" is executed. I'm keeping the results of the of that function for the entire session and using it to store the user's input: store = session.get('store'). If the user hits the homepage(/) again or 5 minutes is up the session is over. Actually, when the user hits the homepage, the function store is executed again. Am I missing anything? How would I let Flask know that my session has began(login) and ended(logout)?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template,redirect,request,url_for, flash,  session
from Index_generator import index_generator
from Yelp_api import request_yelp
from plaid import auth
from search_results import search,search1
from Options import return_data
from datetime import timedelta
import os
import time
from path import path_data
import logging
from logging_path import log_dir
logger = logging.getLogger("Routing")
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
foodie_log = log_dir()
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %  (message)s')
foodie_log.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(foodie_log)
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'mykeysoooooooooolong24char'
go = path_data()
@app.before_request
def make_session_permanent():
    session.permanent = True
    app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(seconds=300)
@app.route('/')
def home():
    store = index_generator()
    session['store'] = store
    return render_template('home.html')
@app.route('/about')
def about():
  return render_template('about.html')
@app.route('/home_city',methods = ['POST'])
def home_city():
    try:
        CITY=request.form['city']
        store = session.get('store')
        request_yelp(DEFAULT_LOCATION=CITY,data_store=store)
        return render_template('bank.html')
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(e)
        error = 'Sorry, no results. Is' + ' ' +CITY + ' '+ 'your hometown? If not, try again and if so, we have been made aware of the issue and is working to resolve it'
    return render_template('home.html',error=error)
@app.route('/traveling',methods = ['POST'])
def travel():
    store = session.get('store')
    answer=request.form['Travel']
    if answer == 'yes':
        #time.sleep(2)
        return render_template('destination.html')
    else:
        results_home = search(index=store)
    time.sleep(2)
    return return_data(results_home)
@app.route('/dest_city',methods = ['POST'])
def dest_city():
    store = session.get('store')
    try:
        DESTINATION=request.form['dest_city']
        request_yelp(DEFAULT_LOCATION=DESTINATION, data_store=store,sourcetype='dest_city')
        results_dest = search1(index=store)
        time.sleep(2)
        return return_data(results_dest)
 except urllib2.HTTPError:
    error = 'Sorry, no results. Is your destination city? If not, try again and if so, we have been made aware of the issue and is working to resolve it'
   return render_template('destination.html',error=error)

@app.route('/bank',methods = ['POST'])
def bank():
   try:
        store = session.get('store')
        print store
        Bank=request.form['Fin_Bank']
        Username=request.form['username']
        Password=request.form['password']
        Test =  auth(account=Bank,username=Username,password=Password,data_store=store)
        if Test == 402 or Test ==401:
            error = 'Invalid credentials'
            return render_template('bank.html',error=error)
        else:
            return render_template('travel.html')
    except:
        logger.error(e)
if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
  app.secret_key='shhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pointing you to the fact that the view function for the URL `/bank` has not returned a value, hence Flask doesn't know what to respond to the web client.

Looking at the function `bank` reveals that indeed there is a code path that does not return a value. That is, if the function encounters an exception, it tries to log the exception (`logger.error(e)`) but then does not return a value. In Flask, a view function should always return a response. In your case, you could use a similar approach to what you did in `home_city` when it encounters an error - returning the same template with an error message.

Actually the 'except' line in `bank()` should be changed to `except Exception as e:` (just like in `home_city`), because you can't log the exception if you're not catching it.

Once you know what the actual exception is that is being encountered by the `bank` function, you can fix it accordingly.